# Bootpag pagination next and back button - skip 8 set by set

Tags: jquery, pagination

I am using bootpag pagination. It was really good. I am using the advanced example in below fiddle

When I click next button it'll go to next set of pages, then if I hit back button it goes to first set of pages but it starts to go one by one page when I keep pressing back button. I want to disable the back button when I am in first set of pages as well as when I am in last set of pages I want to disable next button.

I want to disable "go to each page by page" in every occasion and I want to go 8 set by set when I hit next button and back button.

Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/chrishanmx/3rfdus3c/  fiddle link